# pagination bootstrap class dosent work how to fix this

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

this is my some of pagination code using bootstrap,bootstraps styling property dosent appear in it what can i do?

```
 <ul class="pagination" >
      <?php // if($page_no > 1){ echo "<li><a href='?page_no=1'>First Page</a></li>"; } ?>

    <li <?php if($page_no <= 1){ echo "class='disabled'"; } ?>>
        <a <?php if($page_no > 1){ echo "href='?page_no=$previous_page'"; } ?>>Previous</a>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want bootstrap styles then you need to include all the needed classes for this. Please check an example above and try to add classes for the list item and a link.

```
<ul class="pagination">
  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Previous</a></li>
  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a></li>
</ul>
```